# Replace multiple orverlapping values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe containing column `'demo'`. This column contains values such as 20,30,40,50. I want to replace 20 with 30 and 30 with 20.Other values remains as it is. How to do this using pandas or scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas`, specifically the [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function. You can pass it a dictionary of multiple values to replace, where the keys in the dictionary get replaced by the values.

```
df['demo'].replace({20:30, 30:20}, inplace=True)
```

**Example**:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'demo':[20,30,40,50,20,30,30,20]})

>>> df
   demo
0    20
1    30
2    40
3    50
4    20
5    30
6    30
7    20

>>> df['demo'].replace({20:30, 30:20}, inplace=True)
>>> df
   demo
0    30
1    20
2    40
3    50
4    30
5    20
6    20
7    30
```